# Classify collection of images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, scikit-learn

I have folder with collection of images from microscope and I have to separate them into two classes (samples with defects and without defects). Additionally I've got sets of already classified images.
I never tried something like that before so does anyone have example of how to do it using python scikit library?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for.  Are you asking for a way separate the two kinds of files programmatically, or are you asking for tips on an algorithm to decide if an image has defects?  How did the already classified images get classified?

Comment: What features of the image indicate a defect?

Comment: I'm asking for tips on an algorithm to decide if an image has defects. Images from control set were classified by visual analysis

Comment: Images have black net If mesh is smaller than the sample is more corrupt.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a question for here, but since there's a programmatic side, I'd try to help.

This is just one solution, mind you.

The problem breaks down to:

1. In these kinds of problems, first thing you need to do is figure out what "features" of the photos will distinguish the two. Example,maybe the "good" class generally has more curved lines / circles in it, and the "bad" class has mor linear/sharp lines. Or maybe one class is more light and the other dark, etc.
2. The second part, is for each such "feature" create a method that would score a value for an image. So each photo will get a value (say between 0.0-1.0, but not necessary), and then each photo has a feature vector.
3. Using the inputs of the feature vector for each image in the training set, you can then train a decision tree. Look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html, it really helped me.
4. Once you have the classifier ready, you just apply here.
5. Mind you, the whole art here is creating the right "features".

Alternatively, you might want to look ath the Violla-Jones image classifier, you can use OpenCV to train this.
1. Explanation of how to train a classifier: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html
2. The paper explaining it: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf
3. a tutorial http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

hope this helps

Comment: For features, it might be good to look at the fast literature. Also maybe at scikit-image.